# How to enable gitlab-ci-runner to keep docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-container

My Gitlab-Ci Job is failed, which is excuted by docker.

I want to attach to the docker container to check the system-environment.

But the docker container was removed by gitlab-runner automaticly.

How to disable  removing the docker container ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to modify the script to hide the fact that it is failing and give yourself enough time to attach. For example:

```
build-job:
    stage: build
    script:
    - this-step-is-failing.sh
```

would be modified to:

```
build-job:
    stage: build
    script:
    - this-step-is-failing.sh || true
    - sleep 86400
```

This should give you 24 hours to investigate.

Edit: you have to change the default timeout from 1h to 24h under:
`Your Project -> CI/CD Settings -> General pipelines -> Timeout`